# Correct way to capture `host` portion of fully qualified domain name

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I have a `hostName` string which may or may not be a fully qualified domain name.

```
hostName = host1.abc.com  OR

hostName = host1
```

In case `hostName` is a fully qualified domain name, then I need to capture only the first portion in `host`

```
host = host1
```

I have written the following but it is giving empty string `""` when the `hostName` is not a fully qualified domain name

```
const host = hostName.substring(0, hostName.indexOf('.'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way it will give the hostname correctly, in any of the 2 scenarios

`const host = hostName.split('.')[0];`

Or else

`const idx = hostName.indexOf('.');`

`const host = idx > 0 ? hostName.substring(0, idx) : hostName;`

Comment: What's the point of checking if the split array is greater than 1? It should still work if you just do `const host = hostName.split('.')[0]`

Comment: Yes, true.And thanks for mentioning it! I just noticed it. Then the answer would be 
`const host = hostName.split('.')[0];`
And let me edit my original answer for clarity :)
(For the other way only, we would have to check whether the idx is greater than 0)